Oracle AQ and .Net core - How to be notified that a message is available?
Im having a bit of difficulty in creating worker service that will continuously read a AQ…
my expectation is:

Open Connection
Create a Queue Object
Hookup the “myqueue.MessageAvaiable” event
Call “myqueue.Listen()”
Process stuff on the code of item 3, and if everything goes well, “commit” the message (commit in the terms of message queues, not commit as in "commit transaction") like “myqueue.CommitMessage(messageReceived)” or “messageReceived.Commit()”

And i hope to have like 10-15 parallel consumers here because this queue will be very volumetric…
Problem is: its not working... the OnMessageAvailable event never triggers...
I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="23.6.1" and my code is
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
using System;

namespace OracleAQReader;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string connectionString = myConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            OracleAQQueue queue = new OracleAQQueue("BR_AQADM.AQ_TRANSACTIONNOTIFICATION", connection, OracleAQMessageType.Udt, "BR_AQADM.TJSONRESPONSE")
            {
                NotificationConsumers = ["TRANSACTIONSSUBSCRIBER"],
                DequeueOptions = new OracleAQDequeueOptions
                {
                    Wait = 0,
                    ConsumerName = "TRANSACTIONSSUBSCRIBER",
                    NavigationMode = OracleAQNavigationMode.NextMessage,
                    DequeueMode = OracleAQDequeueMode.Remove
                }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Connection State:"+queue.Connection.State);

            queue.MessageAvailable += OnMessageAvailable;

            var msg = queue.Dequeue();
            Console.WriteLine("msg:"+msg.Payload.ToString());

            // Start listening for messages
            Console.WriteLine(queue.Listen(new[] { "TRANSACTIONSSUBSCRIBER" }));
            Console.WriteLine("Listening for messages...");

            // Keep the application running
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    static void OnMessageAvailable(object sender, OracleAQMessageAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        OracleAQQueue queue = (OracleAQQueue)sender;
        OracleAQMessage message = queue.Dequeue();
        byte[] payload = message.Payload as byte[];
        string messageContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload);
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: {messageContent}");
    }
}

public class TJsonResponse : IOracleCustomType, INullable
{
    [OracleObjectMapping("RESPONSE")]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    public bool IsNull {  get; set; }

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new TJsonResponse();
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt)
    {
        OracleUdt.SetValue(con, udt, "RESPONSE", Response);
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, object udt)
    {
        Response = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, udt, "RESPONSE");
    }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("BR_AQADM.TJSONRESPONSE")]
public class TJsonResponseTypeFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory
{
    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new TJsonResponse();
    }
}

